# why AdMob don't show every time a ad?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, admob

I have correctly insert my AdMob banner yesterday but it has never work since now.

I have seen for the first time my ad but now it doesn't again...

Someone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because of the [fill rate](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/kb/#statschange).

You can use [AdSense](http://helpcenter.admob.com/content/enabling-google-adsense-ads-your-applications) to help backfill ads when AdMod does not have any available.