# Admob adds not showing up?

Tags: android, admob

I have a problem with showing admob adds. First I thought that maybe it is because my app is not published yet, so maybe that is the problem. But after some time spent on this forum (and checking my LogCat) I realized that that was not the case.
I am struggling with this for a few days now, so please of someone knows what the problem is, let me know!

this is what it shows up in the LogCat:

```
 Refreshing ad.
 adRequestUrlHtml: ...
 Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
 Received ad url: ....
 nativeDestroy view: 0x386e18
 onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.)
```

Please help me!! Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link an AdSense account to your AdMob to backfill ads when AdMod does not have any available.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975028/why-admob-dont-show-every-time-a-ad/6976030#6976030) for links.